# Нужны ли запятые, указанные в скобках?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*На этом месте(,) после сноса старой избушки(,) был построен коттедж*.

Нужны ли запятые, указанные в скобках? Если да, то по какому правилу?

Comment: Не нужны. Предложение простое , и нет никаких причин что-то выделять

Comment: А разве в простом предложении — с одной грамматической основой — запятым нет места? Все знаки могут быть, кроме точки с запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, обстоятельство, выраженное существительным с предлогом, можно выделить, если хотите подчеркнуть его смысл или с его  помощью что-то пояснить. В предложении как раз важно пояснить, что на месте нового коттеджа когда-то стояла старая избушка.

***На этом месте, после сноса старой избушки, был построен коттедж.***

[Розенталь. Обособление обстоятельств](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112).  Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.

**Если же вы просто хотите сказать, что  на этом месте был построен коттедж, и неважно, что было на этом месте до коттеджа, то тогда запятые можно не ставить.**

Comment: Совершенно верно. Если необходимо подчеркнуть то, ЧТО именно находилось на месте постройки коттеджа (старая избушка, или гнилое болото, или пожарище, или — вдруг! — метеорит упал), тогда, конечно, запятые нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны. Это простое предложение, и нет никаких причин что-то выделять.